# How to re-use the root path for the landing page and as the default path for logged in users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-routing

I want *foo.com/* to show the landing page when the user isn't logged in, and *foo.com/* to show the dashboard of the user when the user is logged in, just like in Facebook.

I was going to do it the following way:

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
    @posts = current_user.posts
    render 'home/dashboard'
  else
    render 'home/landing'
  end
end
```

But then quickly realized that I'd need to use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in order to get `current_user`, so Devise will require to sign in.

Maybe there's a way to do this more cleanly using routing. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: "users#index", as: :authenticated_root
end

unauthenticated do
  root to: "main#index"
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2393#issuecomment-17298414